# How can graphic design help improve internal communications?

Tags: designers

From a personal point of view, I'm convinced you have to enjoy going to the place you work in. Improving your day to day experience feels revolutionary enough for me.

I also think design and usability can improve not only the way a company thinks about new products and customers think about the company, but also how the company sees itself internally. I work in software development, and we usually talk about innovation, atmosphere, team building and all that.

I'm trying to think what I can do, as a designer, to make internal communications more fluent and fun. I'm struggling with the actual ideas. For example, graphs are great, they can show survey results and motivate people to improve... newsletters are fine, nobody really reads them but they are something. Magazine-like publications are good too. And that's as far as I've come.

Can you think of any other ways design can help internal communications?

Comment: Im not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. What are you trying to improve and for what goal?

Comment: @Ryan The way information is distributed inside the company. One side of it could be productivity. I imagine something like a graph showing the self-evaluation for productivity of a certain month, and a following of it.

Comment: Its still too broad. How can I use graphic design internally to do what? What is the function and don't say boost morale because that's just too broad. You could make silly comics for that or custom desktop wallpapers for coworkers. What specifically are you trying to do, otherwise I think this will need to be closed as a brain storming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphic Design is part of internal CI as well as external. People take pride in their work and workplace. Working in software design myself I know that sometimes small things in internal communication can make a big difference. Be it as small as presentation templates, application icons (for internal software), quality staff photos or even custom designed package tape (true story). People do get excited about a designed work-environment. So I would focus on designing that rather than designing how people communicate.